# react-navigation goBack() make Pressable unresponsive for certain seconds

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react native, I use react-navigation to manage my app navigation. But, it turns out that react-navigation causing Pressable element cannot be clicked for certain milliseconds.

Footage:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13s9kD2VvJYghOcv6vZtjE22vU8-Yt5SB/view?usp=sharing
I keep spam click the middle button, however, the 'GO TO PROFILE' button doesn't react as soon as I clicked (there's a delay before it can be clicked).

Here's the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@xenavrt/moving-between-screens-%7C-react-navigation).
Here are my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { CardStyleInterpolators, createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            gestureEnabled: true,
            gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
            cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
          }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I'm expecting a quicker delay time before the button can be pressed again (like the 'GO BACK' button). I tried to use `.goBack(null)` to prevent the previous screen being rerendered, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried on a production build? Debug builds by nature are slower.

Comment: I did, and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

P.S. The best solution would be to just use "@react-navigation/native-stack" instead of "@react-navigation/stack"

---

Today I came to the conclusion that the reason may be the use of the default parameter

```
screenOptions={{
      animationEnabled: true
    }}
```

After setting the state to false, there is no longer a delay on pressing the button, but the animation will no longer work either.

Here is the simplest example

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Screen1 = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleGoToScreen2 = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Screen2');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is Screen 1</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Screen 2" onPress={handleGoToScreen2} />
    </View>
  );
};

const Screen2 = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleGoBack = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is Screen 2</Text>
      <Button title="Go Back" onPress={handleGoBack} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          animationEnabled: false, // Disable transition animation.
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

I also plan to create a ticket on the GitHub page of the developers "navigation", labeled as a bug.